# Word Mail Merge Fields

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I have not worked with Mail Merge fields before and everything I find requires you to select a data source prior to be able to insert merge fields. All I want to do is place fields on the word document and not merge it down until its consumed by the code. I essentially am creating document templates. How is this done in word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would follow this Microsoft [article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA010349201033.aspx).  If you don't have the data source available, I would simply create a dummy Excel/Access/data source with the fields that you will have.   Word prefers to know what fields are available and you can change the source once your template document is built.

Answer (score 16):

As Noah said, it is probably easiest to set up a dummy data source containing the available fields, especially if you haven't worked with Mail Merge before.

However, Word fields can be created completed manually. Press `Alt+I` and then `F` (on an English Word) to open the *Insert Fields* dialog (For Word XP/2003 you will find the same in the *Insert* menu, for Word 2007 the dialog is available from the *Insert* tab of the ribbon under *Quick Parts*). In this dialog you can select the mail merge fields and specify all relevant options, e.g. a field of type `MergeField`.

If you know the field code (and the relevant options) you can also insert the field directly by pressing `Ctrl+F9` followed by the field code (Note that you can toggle the display of field codes using `Alt+F9`). This is a very convenient - albeit advanced - way when creating templates.

Comment: This is a great tip to save (in my case) unnecessary effort to setup a fake datasource - thanks

Comment: Awesome. Just what I was looking for

Comment: I've been coding professionally for 18 years and somehow managed to avoid doing a Word MailMerge all this time - you just helped me out big-time!

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  This inspired me to try removing the data source after creating a merge doc the regular way.  Edited word\recipientData.xml and word\ _rels\settings.xml.rels (files inside the .zip with .dotx extention.)  Exactly what I wa looking for.